# Pinning PublicKey with AlamoFire

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire, pinning

I've been trying to perform a [public key pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#Public_Key) for my application.

And I did the following steps:

1) First I used openssl to extract the server cert in der format

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect my.server.com:443 < /dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER > serverCert.der`

2) Loaded publicKey from cert:

```
    func getPubKey() -> SecKey? {
        let certificateData = NSData(contentsOfURL:NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("serverCert", withExtension: "der")!)

        let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certificateData!)

        var trust: SecTrustRef?

        let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()
        let status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certificate!, policy, &trust)

        var key: SecKey?
        if status == errSecSuccess {
            key = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust!)!;
            print("NetworkImplementation :: getPubKey :: success")
        }
        return key
    }
```

3) added my serverTrustPolicy to Alamofire’s Manager:

```
    let key: SecKey? = self.getPubKey()

    self.serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.PinPublicKeys(publicKeys: [key!],
                                                             validateCertificateChain: true,
                                                             validateHost: true)

    self.serverTrustPolicies = [
        "*.my.server.com": self.serverTrustPolicy!
    ]

    self.afManager = Manager(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
                             serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: self.serverTrustPolicies))

    print("NetworkImplementation :: init :: success")
```

4) When I want to perform a request I do this:

```
self.afManager
        .request(almethod, url, parameters: alparams, encoding: encoding, headers: alheaders)
         .validate()
        .response { //... }
```

Then I tried to check if it was not trusting a self signed certificate, to do that I used [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com) and the iOS Simulator.

After installing Charles, added my server domain to the SSL Proxy configuration on port 443 and clicked **Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install on simulators**.

I was able to see the request and response content of my application inside the Charles UI and the request connection status was not an error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try it on device and add proxy to that device? I'm not sure if it matters, both your simulator and Mac desktop is the same machine.

Comment: @KennyLim I did tried, but Charles gives me an ipv6 address on port 4444, I did not figured out how to set those on the device's HTTP proxy configuration. Could you help me out?

Comment: any further solution ?? I face this problem too : (